# Draw quad (interleaved) in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl, quad

I'm trying to draw a quad in three.js, but three.js keeps complaining that 'tex' is not a 'WebGLTexture' and refuse to run, what's going on here? thank you.

```
// z= depth, tex is texture
function drawQuad(z, tex)
{
  var verts = [      
    -1.0,  1.0, z, 0.0, 1.0,
    -1.0, -1.0, z, 0.0, 0.0,
    1.0,  1.0, z, 1.0, 1.0,
    1.0, -1.0, z, 1.0, 0.0,      
  ];    

  const gl = renderer.getContext();  

  gl.disable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);

  gl.useProgram(quadShader);

  var vb = gl.createBuffer();
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vb);
  gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(verts), gl.STATIC_DRAW);    

  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vb);

  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(0);  
  gl.vertexAttribPointer(0, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 20, 0);

  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(1);  
  gl.vertexAttribPointer(1, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 20, 12);  

  gl.uniform1i(gl.getUniformLocation(quadShader, 'su_tex'), 0)
  gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0 + 0);     
  gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, tex);   

  gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4) 
  
  gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);
}
```

tex is loaded like this

```
wallTex = loader.load("https://r105.threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/resources/images/wall.jpg");
drawQuad(1.0, wallTex);
```

Comment: `tex` is a [`THREE.Texture`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/textures/Texture) object, but not a `WebGLTexture` object created with  [`gl.createTexture()`](https://registry.khronos.org/webgl/specs/latest/1.0/#5.14.8).

Comment: Thank you, I spent 5 hours and finally figured it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i've figured it out.

Anyway, this may help those who are still confused (c++ opengl pragrammers):

1. `WebGlTexture` is the id you created with `glGenTextures(1, &texturId)`, it is for rendering.
2. `THREE.js.Texture` is a texture container, it contains texture descriptions and image data downloaded from web or whatever, it has a hidden property `__webglTexture` which is null if this THREE.js.Texture never been used for rendering. then what if it has been used for rendering? it will create a `WebGLTexture` (via glGenTextures(1, &textureId) internally i guess) and assign this WebGlTexture id to its `__webglTexture`, and now you can use it for rendering.

It might be more appropriate to call `THREE.js.Texture` as `THREE.js.TextrureRes` IMO, less mis-leading.